# KeyError on Generator

Tags: python, generator, networkx

So close, and yet so far.

I'm not sure what happened but a generator script that was working for me has suddenly started throwing KeyErrors. I am assigning properties to networkx nodes according to a category I am giving each node.

Each node looks like this...

```
539943797.0: {'category': 'perimeter'}
```

and I define the sizes with a variable like this...

```
node_sizes = {'core':500, 'perimeter':50}
```

and the actual node draw code looks like this, with the generator in place...

```
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, graph_pos, 
                       node_size=[node_sizes[G.node[node]['category']]for node in G],
                       alpha=node_alpha,  
                       node_color=[node_colors[G.node[node]['category']]for node in G])
```

The problem is, the above generator code (which was working not so long ago) gives me a KeyError:'category' error when I run it.

However, calling this...

```
node_sizes[G.node[539943797.0]['category']]
```

gets me the value of 50, as I would expect; pulling the category from 539943797.0 as 'perimeter' and the size for that is 50. So far so good. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I was hoping another few sets of eyes on this could give me a better idea.

I suspect I'm doing something wrong in how I calling the category, or setting it

(I set it here...)

```
for node in graph[1]:
    G.add_node(node)
    G.node[node]['category'] = 'perimeter'
```

If I need to put up more of the code to be better understood I'll try and trim things up and put it out here. Hopefully I've supplied enough.

thanks,

Comment: For all of the nodes added to `G` from `graph[1]` in the for-loop, this attribute should be fine. But are there any places outside of the for-loop in which `G.add_node` is called (either explicitly or implicitly)? Can they be residual nodes added to `G` from some earlier code, so that `G` is not starting off empty at the beginning of the loop?

Comment: I don't believe it is any residual code. In fact I ended up restarting the kernel , then the whole ide (canopy) to make sure that nothing was going on. The problem manifested itself after the generator code was working fine. I attempted to add edges to the graph and sometime after that the generator portion stopped working, The node object doesn't appear any different however so I'm at a loss for why I can call the 'category' directly, but not through the generator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your comment you say this started happening after you started adding edges.  I think that's where the problem is.  You'll get this error if even one node doesn't have the `'category'` defined.  I think adding edges is resulting in the addition of a few nodes that don't have `category` defined.  The first test is to just go through

```
for node in G.nodes():
    if not G.node[node].has_key('category'):
        print node
```

right before where you get your error.
I bet that you'll see that most of your nodes are okay, but a few aren't.

If I have the code

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_node(1)
G.node[1]['category'] = 'perimeter'
for node in G.nodes():
    if not G.node[node].has_key('category'):
        print node
```

I get no output.  All (1) of the nodes has `'category'` defined.
However, if I then try

```
G.add_edge(1,2)

for node in G.nodes():
    if not G.node[node].has_key('category'):
        print node
```

It outputs

> 2

This is because it when I added the edge, networkx saw a node that wasn't in `G` yet.  It assumes you want to add the node too.  So now you've added a new node `2`, but it doesn't know that it should be defining `'category'` as well.  So it doesn't.

From what you've described this is almost certainly what is happening.  To check this, before adding any edge you can check whether the two nodes are in the graph already.  Or, if your code adds a huge number of edges at once, just check whether `G.order()` is the same before and after.  Once you figure out why it's doing this, presumably you can decide what you want to do with those nodes.

If this doesn't find something that's an issue, then you'll need to post more code, so that we have something that reproduces your error.

Comment: Brilliant! - Thanks, that is exactly what it was. I had a single node that had no category. Since I only have two categories and the nodes are added in separate actions with only 6 core nodes I could easily just use your for loop to add a category to the single node and the network displayed correctly.

Of course now I have to go through and find out why I have this one wayward node, but at least I'm moving forward again. 

Thanks a lot.